# C++: proper format to initialize derived and base along

Tags: c++, inheritance, initialization

I have made a date class that can hold the month, the day, and the year. But now I have a problem.
I've used this date class with inheritance to store for example the dateOfBirth for person(receptionist, passenger, and etc) (A hotel) by the Ctor of person(in fact using Ctor of date class in the initialization list of person), but now I don't know what is the format which I should use in main to initialize a person?! Is there anyway that I can do it directly in main at all? Sorry I'm beginner. Any help appreciated.
Here's some parts of my code:

```
class date {
    int month = 1;
    vector<int>month_days{ 31,31,31,31,31,31,30,30,30,30,30,29 };
    int day = 1;
    int year = 1300;

//---------------------member functions:
public:
    date(int m = 1, int d = 1, int y = 1300) {
        if (m>0 && m <= 31) month = m;
        if (d>0 && d <= 31) day = d;
        if (y>0 && y <= 3000) year = y;
    }
//some other code...
};

class person:public date {
protected:
    string m_name;
    string m_familyName;
    string m_idNumber;
//---------------------member functions:
public:
    person(string name, string familyName, string idNumber, date dateOfBirth) 
        : m_name(name),m_familyName(familyName),m_idNumber(idNumber),date(dateOfBirth)
    {
}
//some other code...
};
```

This is what I typed in main and I know that it can't do the job:

```
person a("Michael", "Deoran", "05174084", (4,17,1998));
```

I checked the stored date for object "a" and its date returns 1,1,1300, nevertheless, I don't know what can do the job too.
(By the way, the reason I defined a date, separate from person, is that I overloaded the operator- in it to calculate the stay time of passenger)

Comment: Off topic, `person` is-**not**-a `date`, `person` should have-a `date`.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is having a `Date` as an attribute of the `Person` class, rather than using inheritance. What attributes or functions of a `Date` can a person have?

Comment: @LogicStuff and alejandrogiron, I know that, but as I've explained, I have no way, I have to define the date. and dateOfBirth "is-a" date. Isn't it?!

Comment: Ok, you need to declare the members of date class prootected, then you may access them from person class. And the assignment should be done explicitly, member by member, in the person constructor

Comment: @SimoneCifani currently I don't have any problems accessing them, I'm not sure what you're going to say.

Comment: A date of birth is clearly a date.   That doesn't mean a person is a date.

Comment: @Peter thanks, yes I think what I've written doesn't make sense. But how can I relate dateOfBirth to date if it "is-a" date, without using inheritance...?

Comment: @M-J you cannot copy dateOfbirth in this way on the person costructor, you could do it member by member. This is due to the poor design, because a person is not a date

Comment: @M-J `date m_dateOfBirth;` - a data member of `person`.

Comment: @LogicStuff indeed I did this in the first place and changed it when didn't work, =) dumb action, sorry, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is change parentheses to braces (that is for the code to compile, not to be also well-designed and not producing `-Wreorder` warnings):

```
person a("Michael", "Deoran", "05174084", {4, 17, 1998});
```

- [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

The version with parentheses is equivalent to (comma operator):

```
person a("Michael", "Deoran", "05174084", 1998);
```

I would think twice before providing default values for the parameters. You probably don't need them.

Comment: Also silently ignoring the range errors in the `date` constructor might not be the best idea. The `1998` gets swallowed, because it's not a valid value for a month, which further adds to the confusion when debugging the problem.

Comment: @LogicStuff I thought default constructor had no usage, I don't need a person with no information. Is it a silly reason!? (That's what happens when a novice tries to be honest 8) )

Comment: @M-J You're right, I assumed your `date` had to be default-constructible (to start of the epoch, for example) as part of some workaround.

Comment: @LogicStuff one subsidiary question: I've corrected my design, should I change my code in the question to prevent confusing probable passers? or I should leave it the way it is? I'm just not fully familiar with the conventions on SO. Thanks a ton for all the help.

Comment: @M-J I wouldn't do so, as it has been discussed in the comments and would invalidate those references. Or it would require deleting the last two sentences from my answer and a lot of comment flagging as obsolete - which you should also do with this comment when you read it and delete your most recent one.